# Why does DataSet.Clear() throw ArgumentOutOfRangeException?

Tags: c#, dataset

This only seems to happen some times

Here is the stack trace:

```
at System.ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentOutOfRangeException(ExceptionArgument argument, ExceptionResource resource)
   at System.ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentOutOfRangeException()
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1.get_Item(Int32 index)
   at System.Data.DataTable.get_LiveIndexes()
   at System.Data.DataTable.SetShadowIndexes()
   at System.Data.DataTable.ResetInternalIndexes(DataColumn column)
   at System.Data.DataTable.Clear(Boolean clearAll)
   at System.Data.DataSet.Clear()
```

Comment: Not sure why this is nominated for closing.  I have seen this question asked over the internet and its not something expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that the problem was caused by multi-threading.  Putting locks around the `DataSet` stopped this exception from happening.

Comment: [Indeed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataset.aspx): `This type is safe for multithreaded read operations. You must synchronize any write operations.`